# How to not inflate fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments inside an layout. I want to show only one fragment at a time. How can I do it?

```
<fragment
    android:name="edu.ucsb.cs.cs190i.pazspm.pazspmdemosuite.SpeechFragment"
    android:id="@+id/demo_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<fragment
    android:name="edu.ucsb.cs.cs190i.pazspm.pazspmdemosuite.TextFragment"
    android:id="@+id/demo2_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options.  Since you haven't said exactly what you're trying to do, I'll just list a few off the top of my head:

- ViewPager
- Create a FrameLayout parent and write code that performs fragment transactions within that container.
- Don't use fragments and just start a new activity to show a whole new set of views.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Linearlayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:oriantation="vertical">
<fragment
     android:name="edu.ucsb.cs.cs190i.pazspm.pazspmdemosuite.SpeechFragment"
     android:id="@+id/demo_fragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
 />

<fragment
    android:name="edu.ucsb.cs.cs190i.pazspm.pazspmdemosuite.TextFragment"
    android:id="@+id/demo2_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</Linearlayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked.  How does this show only one at a time?

Comment: u can use framelayout